# Restangular and HATEOAS API

Tags: angularjs, spring, restangular, hateoas

I use Spring Boot application and @RepositoryRestResource to implement my REST API. For Project entity I got the following output:

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "projects" : [ {
      "name" : "Test project",
      "createDate" : "2016-02-13",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/projects/1"
        },
        "project" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/projects/1"
        },
        "tasks" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/projects/1/tasks"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/projects"
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/profile/projects"
    }
  }
}
```

As we have resource self link instead of database identity it becomes a question how to make navigation between states correctly. I had the following setup before:

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('projects', {
        url: '/projects',
        templateUrl: 'partials/projects.html',
        controller: 'ProjectListController'
    }).state('project', {
        url: '/project/:id',
        templateUrl: 'partials/project-view.html',
        controller: 'ProjectViewController'
...
```

and to open project info page I passed id to the state.go({id:project.id}) or from ui-sref or open URL: http://localhost:8080/index.html#/projects/1

Now I pass _self.href as hidden param to state function

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('projects', {
        url: '/projects',
        templateUrl: 'partials/projects.html',
        controller: 'ProjectListController'
    }).state('viewProject', {
        url: '/project',
        templateUrl: 'partials/project-view.html',
        controller: 'ProjectViewController',
        params: {'href':null}
...
```

And it works. But as the URL doesn't contain id I could not open project info page using old link: http://localhost:8080/index.html#/projects/1

I've seen a lot of examples but niether one helped as most of them has one state only.

Thanks in advance.